# How can I insert a "Select All" item at the top of a ComboBox with its ItemsSource set?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` with its `ItemsSource` set to an `IList` of `MyClass` objects.  I overrode the `ComboBox`'s `ItemTemplate` to display a `CheckBox` next to the items.  I want to have an item at the top that says "Select All" and when the user checks that `CheckBox`, the code checks all `CheckBoxes`.  My question is, what is the MVVM way of doing this?

I don't want to add a separate `MyClass` object to the `IList`.  That seems like it would involve too much coupling of the view and the model.  Is there a way to add an item directly in the XAML code and give it a `Command` that checks all of the `Checkboxes`?

My `ComboBox` XAML right now is:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" Width="200">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding Selected}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

That looks like:

[image]

I'd like it to look like:

[image]

My MyClass is simply this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

Edit: I found a way to add an item to the collection in the XAML code using [the example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18671764/how-to-add-option-all-to-a-combobox-in-wpf-with-binding-from-database).  I would still need a way run code when the user checks the checkbox for that "Select All" item.  To just add the item, the code is this:

```
<ComboBox Width="200">

    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="comboBoxSource" Source="{Binding Path=MyList}" />
    </ComboBox.Resources>

    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <local:MyClass Name="Select All" Selected="False">
            </local:MyClass>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource comboBoxSource}}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>

    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding Selected}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do it that uses some simpler concepts.

My first problem was that I wanted to add a "Select All" item to the top of the list without actually adding an item to the databound `IList<MyClass>`.  I edited my original post to show that I can use a `CompositeCollection` to do this.  I made the "Select All" databound object a subclass of `MyClass` and called the class `MyClassSelectAll`.  More on this below.

My second problem was that I needed to handle the `CheckBox.Click` event differently for the "Select All" item than for the regular `MyClass` items.  I gave each `CheckBox` a `Command` that I can use to check the `CheckBoxes`.  To do this, I need a reference to both the `IList<MyClass>` and the `CheckBox` on which the user clicked (more specfically the `MyClass` object databound to that `CheckBox`).

I found one way to solve my second problem is to set the `CheckBox.CommandParameter` to a `MultiBinding` that contains those two objects.  In the `Command.Execute(object)` method, I can easily check if the current `MyClass` is a `MyClassSelectAll`, and if so, I can loop through the `IList<MyClass>` list (which doesn't contain the "Select All" item) and set the "Selected" property appropriately.

Here's my relevant XAML code:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <local:MyCommand x:Key="kMyCommand" />
    <local:MyConverter x:Key="kConv" />
</Grid.Resources>

<ComboBox Width="200">

    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="comboBoxSource" Source="{Binding Path=MyList}" />
    </ComboBox.Resources>

    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <local:MyClassSelectAll Name="Select All" Selected="False" />
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding 
                Source={StaticResource comboBoxSource}}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>

    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" 
                IsChecked="{Binding Selected}" 
                Command="{StaticResource kMyCommand}">
                <CheckBox.CommandParameter>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource kConv}">
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource 
                            FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}" 
                            Path="DataContext.MyList" />
                        <Binding Path="." />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </CheckBox.CommandParameter>
            </CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

</ComboBox>
```

I updated `MyClass` to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` appropriately.  The code is simple, so I won't post it here.

`MyConverter` is pretty simple as well; it just packages the list and current item object into a `MyCommandArgs` object:

```
class MyConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        MyCommandArgs result = new MyCommandArgs()
        {
            MyList = values[0] as IList<MyClass>,
            CurrentItem = values[1] as MyClass
        };
        return result;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, 
        object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The `MyCommandArgs` class that I use to pass around the `MyList` and `CurrentItem` references is a simple container class so I won't post it here.

`MyClassSelectAll` is the simplest; its only job is to flag the "Select All" `MyClass` object as something that selects all.

```
class MyClassSelectAll : MyClass
{
}
```

Finally, The `MyCommand` object that handles the click event.

```
class MyCommand : ICommand
{
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        var mylist = parameter as MyCommandArgs;
        if (mylist != null && mylist.CurrentItem is MyClassSelectAll)
        {
            foreach (var item in mylist.MyList)
            {
                item.Selected = mylist.CurrentItem.Selected;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks everyone.  I was really stuck on this.  It seems like many times when I have a problem doing something in WPF, the solution is to use a `Converter`.

Answer (score 2):

Id personally just modify the CheckBox's Template and add custom CheckBox there with Click handler, nothing too fancy, easy to understand.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094(v=vs.110).aspx

From there you can modify this part:

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"
                                KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

The other way I would model is this simply as to create

```
public class MyClassViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }

    public ICommand Execute {get; set;}
}
```

and add custom object to your IList. This will work nicely, without any crap, your viewmodel has no idea about view, + it's testable. win-win for everyone.

Comment: If you want to complicate things, you can theoretically create new MyClassSelectAll class and add it to CompositeCollection & create new DataTemplate for that specific type & hook to CheckBoxs CHecked event.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to your suggestion.  I used a command instead of the Checked event.  I'm not sure how to modify the checkbox template, and I didn't want to change my `MyClass` class.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever your Button to select all is pressed you can invoke action, binding to itemssource, enumerating throughout collection setting Selected value to true. This solutiond requires Blend interface.

```
 <local:MyClass Name="Select All" Selected="False">
          <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <ic:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Selected}" Value="True">
                            <local:SelectAll TargetObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBox}, Path=ItemsSource}"/>
                </ic:DataTrigger>
           </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</local:MyClass>
```

and then create class SelectAll as follows

```
public class SelectAll : TargetedTriggerAction<List<MyClass>>
{
    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        if (Target is List<MyClass>)
            foreach (var elem in (List<MyClass>)Target)
                elem.Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to registed the event when selecting a item, and when selecting the item,check that the item selected is the first one(using index) and then,change the selection to what do you need.
(Dont have the IDE here,sorry for not code).

Comment: This sounds like the WinForms way of doing this.  This would lead to the tight-coupling that I alluded to above when I mentioned inserting an item at the top of MyList.